# Performance of large number of classes vs. methods in Java

Tags: java, performance, reflection, code-generation, dsl

I am implementing a DSL, which will generate Java classes and methods.

Because of the nature of the language, it will be separated into a runtime and a generated library, which the runtime will operate over.

I have two options for implementing this library, and am wondering if either is a known better practice.

In general, generated code will not be loaded up front. The generated classes will be loaded as needed, via Reflection, with a separate classloader to allow for class unloading as determined by the JVM. Reflection will operate directly over String literals in an index in the generated code to eliminate the need for intensive introspection.

- Option 1: My language code blocks all map to classes. This means generating a large number of classes, many of which will be inner classes, to implement nested scoping. The outer classes will be instantiated via reflection from the runtime as needed, and the inner classes will then be directly constructed and utilized.
- Option 2: My top level language constructs map to container classes, which will be instantiated via reflection from the runtime as needed. Nested constructs will map to methods within these container classes, which will be invoked by reflection from the runtime.

So, the main question is - **which will perform better, if there is a significant difference?**

For practical consideration, we're probably looking at a comparison between approximately

- Option 1: 50,000 classes (10,000 outer, 40,000 inner)
- Option 2: 10,000, with 4 methods each, to be invoked via reflection

Comment: I think unfortunately, this is opinion based.  If you're generating the code though, why try both?  Profile the code and see which runs better.  50,000 classes is insane imo, but reflection is a terrible idea too.  My guess is either idea is unacceptable.  Devise something better.

Comment: Ok, I'm just wondering if there is a known best practice or performance-based answer. Again, these classes will not be used directly by any programmers. This is purely the executable output of a DSL. It is fine if it is unwieldy for a human to use directly.

Comment: By "unacceptable" I was including the idea of the JVM loading 50,000 classes from disc.  It's probably going to be slow, and unwieldy for the GC to manage.  Likewise reflection is a known bottleneck.  You should try them out to be sure but I think neither one is going to perform well.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I should mention that the classes would not be loaded up-front. I would load them, via Reflection, as needed. I ran a test over 100,000 classes and didn't see any problems. These are small classes. I used my own classloader, but still never saw one unloaded.

As for the reflection route, I wouldn't be doing intensive introspection. The generated code would contain an index with the String literal forms of classes/methods to access. It would just be direct calls of methods like Class.forName and getDeclaredMethod().

Comment: I'm kind of shocked that 100k classes didn't give the JVM a heart attack, but if testing is going well then I think you should proceed.  Maybe toss some of your code prototypes on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to share and get ideas for better performance.

Comment: Cool, will look into that. Yeah, it worked fine. It definitely chugged up eclipse up for workspace builds, though :)